# Coloring layers from png in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am stuck with an application I intend to develop, which is a drawing tool. What I want is a tool which will draw a png outline picture. The solution what I can imagine so far is having the different parts as separate png images and create a layer with each of them and on mousedown event selecting the specific layer to draw and then color it as per need.

With very limited knowledge over canvas I have come across to a general query that if I can create such layers from png files of same dimensions ? If so, will it be selectable when the event occurs on canvas ? What should be the best process to follow in terms of achieving the expected result. Any guidance regarding this will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

N.B> I have come across a very useful library here https://bitbucket.org/ant512/canvaslayers/wiki/Tutorial_4.wiki, which does something similar but with shapes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by PNG Outline Picture - do you mean a border that uses an image?

Comment: Yes. It is just an outline picture and having the section to be colored as png with transparent backgrounds for layer reference. Just imagine a photoshop doc, where we have layers as transparent background and filled with colors for the respective portion only.